# Haskell type-mapping (-> operator) in where clause?

Tags: haskell, types, where-clause

I am trying to understand the code in [this article](http://jelv.is/blog/Generating-Mazes-with-Inductive-Graphs/). It explains the use of inductive graphs, which seems very nice, and at some point it defines a depth-first search for inductive graphs. The code for it is the following:

```
dfs :: Graph.Node -> Gr a b -> [Node]
dfs start graph = go [start] graph
  where go [] _                            = []
        go _ g | Graph.isEmpty g           = []
        go (n:ns) (match n -> (Just c, g)) =
          n : go (Graph.neighbors' c ++ ns) g
        go (_:ns)
```

I do not understand these two lines:

```
        go (n:ns) (match n -> (Just c, g)) =
          n : go (Graph.neighbors' c ++ ns) g
```

It seems it is defining the function `go`, which takes a list as a first argument, which is pattern-matched by `(n:ns)`. The second argument, however, I do not understand: `(match n -> (Just c, g))`. What does the operator `->` mean here? By looking the operator up, it can be one of three things:

- Function type-mapping operator.
- Lambda definition operator.
- Separator in case construction.

Since there is no `case` statement, nor a backslash-escaped variable for a lambda expression, it can only be the case that it is the function type-mapping operator. In this case, I don't get how it is binding values to these variables, `c` and `g`? And what does it mean exactly, how can it be in an argument?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`->` means neither function-type nor lambda-definition nor case-mapping in this case. It is a [view pattern](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).

```
go (n:ns) (match n -> (Just c, g)) =
      n : go (Graph.neighbors' c ++ ns) g
```

is equivalent to

```
go (n:ns) g'
  | (Just c, g) <- match n g'
        = n : go (Graph.neighbors' c ++ ns) g
```

where the [pattern guard](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pattern_guard) `(Just c, g) <- match n g'` is in turn short for

```
go (n:ns) g' = case match n g' of
   (Just c, g) -> n : go (Graph.neighbors' c ++ ns) g
   (Nothing, g) -> ...
```

where the `Nothing` clause needs to stand in for the later clause of the `go` definition.

Answer (score 3):

It is a [view pattern](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-02-view-patterns.html). This extension lets us transform the argument somehow before matching on it.

Without this extension, the code would have to be written like this:

```
go (n:ns) g' =
  case match n g' of
    (Just c, g) -> ...
    ...
```

which is a bit more verbose.

Comment: You need an extra parameter, e.g `go (n:ns) g' = case match n g' of ...`.